# SQL query to join same table with SUM up until each returned row

Tags: mysql, sql

I came across a task where I have to return the total COUNT and SUM of issued policies for each day of the month and compare it to the previous year.

Table PolicyOrder has fields:

PolicyOrderId - primary key
CreatedAt (DATETIME)
CalculatedPremium - cost of policy or "premium"
PolicyOrderStatusId - irrelevant to the question but still - status of the policy.

To solve this I came up with a query that inner joins self table and sums/counts by grouping according to DAY of the creation date.

```
SELECT 
      DATE(po1.CreatedAt) AS dayDate_2017, 
      SUM(po1.CalculatedPremium) AS premiumSum_2017,
      COUNT(po1.PolicyOrderId) AS policyCount_2017,
      po2.*
FROM 
      PolicyOrder po1
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT 
                DATE(CreatedAt) AS dayDate_2018, 
                SUM(CalculatedPremium) AS premiumSum_2018, 
                COUNT(PolicyOrderId) AS policyCount_2018
           FROM 
                PolicyOrder po2
           WHERE
                YEAR(CreatedAt) = 2018 AND 
                MONTH(CreatedAt) = 10 AND
                PolicyOrderStatusId = 6 
           GROUP BY
                DAY(CreatedAt)
       ) po2 ON ( 
           DAY(po2.dayDate_2018) = DAY(po1.CreatedAt) 
       )
WHERE   
       YEAR(po1.CreatedAt) = 2017 AND 
       MONTH(po1.CreatedAt) = 10 AND 
       PolicyOrderStatusId = 6 
GROUP BY 
       DAY(po1.CreatedAt)
```

The above query returns these results:

```
dayDate_2017 | premiumSum_2017 | policyCount_2017 | dayDate_2018 | premiumSum_2018 | policyCount_2018
2017-10-01   | 4699.36         | 98               | 2018-10-01   | 8524.21         | 144
2017-10-02   | 9114.55         | 168              | 2018-10-02   | 7942.25         | 140
2017-10-03   | 9512.43         | 178              | 2018-10-03   | 9399.61         | 161
2017-10-04   | 9291.77         | 155              | 2018-10-04   | 6922.83         | 137
2017-10-05   | 8063.27         | 155              | 2018-10-05   | 9278.58         | 178
2017-10-06   | 9743.40         | 184              | 2018-10-06   | 6139.38         | 136
...
2017-10-31   | ...
```

The problem is that now I have to add two more columns in which policies has to be counted and amounts added from the start of the year UP UNTIL each returned row.

```
Desired results:
dayDate_2017 | premiumSum_2017 | policyCount_2017 | sumFromYearBegining | countFromYearBegining 
2017-10-01   | 4699.36         | 98               | 150000.34           | 5332   
2017-10-02   | 9114.55         | 168              | 156230.55           | 5443
2017-10-03   | 9512.43         | 178              | 160232.44           | 5663
    ...
2017-10-31   | ...


WHERE:

sumFromYearBegining (150000.34) - SUM of premiumSum from 2017-01-01 until 2017-10-01 (excluding)
countFromYearBegining (5332) - COUNT of policies from 2017-01-01 until 2017-10-01 (excluding)

sumFromYearBegining (1566239.55) - SUM of premiumSum from 2017-01-01 until 2017-10-02 (excluding)
countFromYearBegining (5443) - COUNT of policies from 2017-01-01 until 2017-10-02 (excluding)

sumFromYearBegining (160232.44) - SUM of premiumSum from 2017-01-01 until 2017-10-02 (excluding)
countFromYearBegining (5663) - COUNT of policies from 2017-01-01 until 2017-10-02 (excluding)
```

I have tried inner joining same table COUNTed and SUMed which failed because I cannot specify the range up to which I need to count and sum, I have tried LEFT joining and then counting, which fails because the results are counted not untill each row result but until the last result etc...

DB Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckM8HyTD6NjLbK41Mq1gct/5

Any help from you SQL ninjas highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you setup a https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: Fiddle added to the question. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckM8HyTD6NjLbK41Mq1gct/4

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ? And, can you access / upgrade to latest version (8.0.2 and above) ?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.5 on a production server. I could upgrade development env but the production server will remain 5.5.

Comment: The desired result example is unclear to me. E.g. why did `countFromYearBegining` increase from 5332 to 5443 (difference of 111) when there were 168 (not 111) new policies on 2017-10-02?

Comment: My appologies. countFromYearBeginning desired result values are made up. I havent calculated them exactly. But the count has to be not from the begining of the month, but from the begining of the year (starting from 2017-01-01 not from 2017-10-01)

Comment: A thoughtfully considered MCVE rarely requires more than a dozen rows to illustrate the problem. Just sayin'!

Comment: @Didzis please check the DB fiddle you shared. It is not giving out any result for your current query as well:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckM8HyTD6NjLbK41Mq1gct/4

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thank you for noticing. Updated the query (month changed to "2") https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckM8HyTD6NjLbK41Mq1gct/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) to calculate Rolling Sum / Count, in absence of Window Functions' availability.

We will first need to determine the Sum and Count for **every day** in the year 2017 (even though you need rows for a particular month only). Because, in order to calculate rolling Sum for the days in March month, we would need the sum/count values from the January, and February month(s) as well. One optimization possibility is that we can restrict calculations from the first month to the require month only.

Note that `ORDER  BY daydate_2017` is necessary in order to be able to calculate rolling sum correctly. By default, data is in unordered fashion. Without defining the order, we cannot guarantee that Sum will be correct.

Also, we need to two levels of sub-select queries. First level is used to calculate the Rolling sum values. Second level is used to restrict the result to February month only. Since `WHERE` is executed before `SELECT`; we cannot restrict the result to February month, in the first level itself.

If you need similar rolling Sum for the year 2018 as well; similar query logic can be implemented in other set of sub-select queries.

```
SELECT dt2_2017.*, dt_2018.*
FROM 
(
SELECT dt_2017.*,
       @totsum := @totsum + dt_2017.premiumsum_2017 AS sumFromYearBegining_2017,
       @totcount := @totcount + dt_2017.policycount_2017 AS countFromYearBeginning_2017
FROM   (SELECT Date(po1.createdat)        AS dayDate_2017,
               Sum(po1.calculatedpremium) AS premiumSum_2017,
               Count(po1.policyorderid)   AS policyCount_2017
        FROM   PolicyOrder AS po1
        WHERE  po1.policyorderstatusid = 6 AND 
               YEAR(po1.createdat) = 2017 AND 
               MONTH(po1.createdat) <= 2 -- calculate upto February for 2017
        GROUP  BY daydate_2017
        ORDER  BY daydate_2017) AS dt_2017
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @totsum := 0, @totcount := 0) AS user_init_vars 
) AS dt2_2017 
INNER JOIN (
             SELECT 
               DATE(po2.CreatedAt) AS dayDate_2018, 
               SUM(po2.CalculatedPremium) AS premiumSum_2018, 
               COUNT(po2.PolicyOrderId) AS policyCount_2018
             FROM 
               PolicyOrder po2
             WHERE
                YEAR(po2.CreatedAt) = 2018 AND 
                MONTH(po2.CreatedAt) = 2 AND
                po2.PolicyOrderStatusId = 6 
             GROUP BY
                dayDate_2018
           ) dt_2018 ON DAY(dt_2018.dayDate_2018) = DAY(dt2_2017.dayDate_2017)   
WHERE YEAR(dt2_2017.daydate_2017) = 2017 AND 
      MONTH(dt2_2017.daydate_2017) = 2;
```

**RESULT:   [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ckM8HyTD6NjLbK41Mq1gct/7)**

```
| dayDate_2017 | premiumSum_2017 | policyCount_2017 | sumFromYearBegining_2017 | countFromYearBeginning_2017 | dayDate_2018 | premiumSum_2018 | policyCount_2018 |
| ------------ | --------------- | ---------------- | ------------------------ | --------------------------- | ------------ | --------------- | ---------------- |
| 2017-02-01   | 4131.16         | 131              | 118346.77                | 3627                        | 2018-02-01   | 8323.91         | 149              |
| 2017-02-02   | 2712.74         | 85               | 121059.51000000001       | 3712                        | 2018-02-02   | 9469.33         | 153              |
| 2017-02-03   | 3888.59         | 111              | 124948.1                 | 3823                        | 2018-02-03   | 6409.21         | 97               |
| 2017-02-04   | 2447.99         | 74               | 127396.09000000001       | 3897                        | 2018-02-04   | 5693.69         | 120              |
| 2017-02-05   | 1437.5          | 45               | 128833.59000000001       | 3942                        | 2018-02-05   | 8574.97         | 129              |
| 2017-02-06   | 4254.48         | 127              | 133088.07                | 4069                        | 2018-02-06   | 8277.51         | 133              |
| 2017-02-07   | 4746.49         | 136              | 137834.56                | 4205                        | 2018-02-07   | 9853.75         | 173              |
| 2017-02-08   | 3898.05         | 125              | 141732.61                | 4330                        | 2018-02-08   | 9116.33         | 144              |
| 2017-02-09   | 8306.86         | 286              | 150039.46999999997       | 4616                        | 2018-02-09   | 8818.32         | 166              |
| 2017-02-10   | 6740.99         | 204              | 156780.45999999996       | 4820                        | 2018-02-10   | 7880.17         | 134              |
| 2017-02-11   | 4290.38         | 133              | 161070.83999999997       | 4953                        | 2018-02-11   | 8394.15         | 180              |
| 2017-02-12   | 3687.58         | 122              | 164758.41999999995       | 5075                        | 2018-02-12   | 10378.29        | 171              |
| 2017-02-13   | 4939.31         | 159              | 169697.72999999995       | 5234                        | 2018-02-13   | 9383.15         | 160              |
```

---

Comment: @Didzis that's very kind of you. I have a lot to learn though. Love such challenging scenarios :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a way that avoids using @variables in the select list, and also avoids analytics (only mysql 8 supports them) you can do it with a semi-cartesian product:

```
WITH prevYr AS(
    SELECT 
        YEAR(CreatedAt) AS year_prev,
        MONTH(CreatedAt) AS month_prev,
        DAY(CreatedAt) AS day_prev,
        SUM(CalculatedPremium) AS premiumSum_prev, 
        COUNT(PolicyOrderId) AS policyCount_prev
    FROM 
        PolicyOrder
    WHERE
        CreatedAt BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28' AND
        PolicyOrderStatusId = 6 
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(CreatedAt), MONTH(CreatedAt), DAY(CreatedAt)
),
currYr AS (
    SELECT 
        YEAR(CreatedAt) AS year_curr,
        MONTH(CreatedAt) AS month_curr,
        DAY(CreatedAt) AS day_curr,
        SUM(CalculatedPremium) AS premiumSum_curr, 
        COUNT(PolicyOrderId) AS policyCount_curr
    FROM 
        PolicyOrder
    WHERE
        CreatedAt BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' AND
        PolicyOrderStatusId = 6 
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(CreatedAt), MONTH(CreatedAt), DAY(CreatedAt)
) 


SELECT 
      *
FROM
       prevYr
       INNER JOIN 
       currYr
       ON  
           currYr.day_curr = prevYr.day_prev

       INNER JOIN
       (
           SELECT 
                main.day_prev AS dayRolling_prev, 
                SUM(pre.premiumSum_prev) AS premiumSumRolling_prev, 
                SUM(pre.policyCount_prev) AS policyCountRolling_prev
           FROM 
                prevYr main LEFT OUTER JOIN prevYr pre ON pre.day_prev < main.day_prev
           GROUP BY
                main.day_prev
        ) rollingPrev
        ON  
           currYr.day_curr = rollingPrev.dayRolling_prev

ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

We summarise the year 2017 and year 2018 data into two CTEs because it makes things a lot cleaner and neater later, particularly for this rolling count. You can probably follow the logic of the CTE easily because it's lifted more or less straight from your query - I only dropped the DATE column in favour of a year/month/date triplet because it made other things cleaner (joins) and can be recombined to a date if needed. I also swapped the WHERE clauses to use `date BETWEEN x  AND y` because this will leverage an index on a column whereas using `YEAR(date) = x AND MONTH(date) = y` might not

The rolling counts works via something I referred to as a semi-cartesian. It's actually a cartesian product; any database join that results in rows from one o both tables multiplying and being represented repeatedly in the output, is a cartesian product. Rather than being a full product (every row crossed with every other row) in this case it uses a less than, so every row is only crossed with a subset of rows. As the date increases, more rows match the predicate, because a date of 30th has 29 rows that are less than it.

This thus causes the following pattern of data:

```
maindate   predate    maincount precount
2017-02-01 NULL       10        NULL

2017-02-02 2017-02-01 20        10

2017-02-03 2017-02-01 30        10
2017-02-03 2017-02-02 30        20

2017-02-04 2017-02-01 40        10
2017-02-04 2017-02-02 40        20
2017-02-04 2017-02-03 40        30
```

You can see that for any given main date, it repeats N - 1 times because there are N - 1 dates lower than in that satisfy the join condition `predate < maindate`

If we group by the maindate and sum the counts associated with each predate, we get the rolling sum of all the pre-counts on that main-date (So, on the 4th day of the month, it's SUM(pre count for dates 1st - 3rd, i.e. 10+20+30 = 60. On the 5th day, we sum the counts for days 1 to 4. On the 6th day, we sum days 1 to 5 etc)